# Initial iterator for generate for-loop

Tags: for-loop, verilog

In a generate loop, you often need to connect the first iteration of wires to your inputs (or some unique set of wires) before the array stuff kicks in.  Pasted below is a snippet from my parameterizable OR-Reduce module (my assignment requires structural verilog, so `oOUt = |adjA` is not legal).

```
for(i=0; i<depth; i=i+1) begin : lvl
  localparam iWidth = p2Width>>i;
  localparam oWidth = iWidth>>1;
  wire [oWidth-1:0] tmp;
  if(i==0) begin
    or2$ reduce [oWidth-1:0]
      (tmp, adjA[iWidth/2-1:0], adjA[iWidth-1:iWidth/2]);
  end else begin
    or2$ reduce [oWidth-1:0]
      (tmp, lvl[i-1].tmp[iWidth/2-1:0], lvl[i-1].tmp[iWidth-1: iWidth/2]);
  end
end
```

I have to put this nasty if-statement to catch the first iteration and connect it to the inputs.  The problem is that I can't just change the initial `i` value to 1 and declare a `lvl[0].tmp` outside of the for-loop.  Here's what I think would look nicer if it were legal.

```
wire [p2Width-1] lvl[0].tmp;
or2$ reduce [oWidth-1:0]
  (lvl[0].tmp, adjA[iWidth/2-1:0], adjA[iWidth-1:iWidth/2]);
for(i=1; i<depth; i=i+1) begin : lvl
  localparam iWidth = p2Width>>i;
  localparam oWidth = iWidth>>1;
  wire [oWidth-1:0] tmp;
  or2$ reduce [oWidth-1:0]
    (tmp, lvl[i-1].tmp[iWidth/2-1:0], lvl[i-1].tmp[iWidth-1: iWidth/2]);
end
```

Is there a way to clean up my generate loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your input array to be one entry wider than required.  I find this often results in more readable code:

```
logic [N_LEVELS:0]      block_inputs;     // Last entry not used, optimised away
logic [N_LEVELS-1:0]    block_outputs;

// Start of pipeline
assign block_inputs[0] = stage1_input;

genvar i;
generate
for (i=0; i<N_LEVELS; i++) begin: levels
    some_block i_some_block (
        .data       (block_inputs[i]),
        .result     (block_outputs[i])
    );

    assign block_inputs[i+1] = block_outputs[i];
end
endgenerate

assign final_result = block_outputs[N_LEVELS-1];
```

Comment: So your solution is to not declare my `tmp` wires in the for-loop, but rather pre-allocate every wire that I'll need within the loop?  I do this sometimes, but some implementations have crazy wiring and it's not always easy to pre-calculate all the wires necessary.  The ability to create these temporary values can make things far easier and cleaner, so I'd like a solution (if possible) that still retains the temporary interconnects.

Comment: @Aggieboy If you want to avoid the if statement within your generate loop I don't think you can avoid pre-allocating at least some of the wiring.  Typically you could re-factor such structural descriptions into a more readable higher-level description but you are prevented from doing that.  I find my example style far easier to read than your OP, would be interesting to see and evaluate other possibilities.